# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#create (Insert does not include newly added column)

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm presently teaching myself ruby on rails following my degree. I'm really new to the language and want to know more about how migrations work.

[Error Of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVSDx.png)

I have updated my existing users table through migration to allow for an additional column 'username' and included some HTML/Ruby to allow the user to enter in the field. I can't fathom how rails generates INSERT SQL statements or updates them upon migration.

Below is my Code for HTML

```html
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.text_field :password %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the schema after migration

[Schema After rake db:migrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twFIH.png)

I must be missing something...

Comment: Your links are missing, so I can't see what you've done, yet... However, have you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: @OwenCarter, Can you post your code in `users_controller.rb`? I have added an answer but its based out of assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the server logs, you should find something like `Unpermitted parameter username`.

You should permit the `username` field in the list of  whitelisted parameters. I assume you have a `user_params` method in your `users_controller.rb`. Modify it to allow the newly created `username` field.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :email)
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel so stupid lol for forgetting that :)!

Comment: Sorry took a while to allow me to do so :)!